# Всплывающее сообщение без нажатия на что либо

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть такая штука - всплывающие окошки на сайтах (я про приличные сайты). Скажем добавили вы товар в корзину - и вуаля. Сделать такое при нажатии на кнопку не беда, гуголь в помощб как говориться. но вот как сделать такое всплывающее окно, в случае если у меня переменная в php равна определенному значению.

Загружается страница. У нее определенная переменная ( $scan ) может быть $scan = 1. Вот в случае если она = 1, можно как то без нажатия сделать всплывающее сообщение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var scan = <?php echo '1'; ?>;
setTimeout(function()
{
    if(scan == 1)
    {
        alert('Беда... scan = 1 :('); //тут всплывающее сообщение
    }
}, 5000); //1000 = 1сек
</script>
```

Comment: все гениально и просто! спасибо.