# Всплывающее окно на сайте ( Не в браузере )

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Доброго всем времени суток

На многих сайтах есть всплывающие окошки. Причем не простые [как это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146844/php-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE) а допустим все что рядом становиться тускнее, само окно - в нем можно прописать все как на отдельной html странице, ест-но нет галки от браузера, что б больше окно не всплывало. Скажите, в какую сторону гуглить, что бы найти аналогичный скрипт. Или приведите простой пример, как это можно сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery FancyBox](http://fancybox.net)

[Modal от Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)